# What is Floor (the rabbit) shouting?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, dialogue, guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol-3

In *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3*, when Rocket uses his homemade key

> to break out of the cages, Lylla gets shot. Immediately afterwards, Floor the rabbit starts hopping in circles and shouting something.

Although I could tell that Floor was repeating the same thing over and over, I couldn't understand a single word of it. What was she shouting?

Comment: I will be curious if there is more than one answer, since there are 600 slightly different cuts/versions of the film!

Comment: @DarthLocke The versions differ in presentation format, not content. For example, an IMAX theater gets a different version than a standard theater. Two screens with different aspect ratios get different versions of the film. A Dolby Atmos theater gets a different version than a theater without Atmos. There may be versions that differ in color depth or even framerate. I'm not clear on whether the 600 versions include localization (e.g. dubs). But you shouldn't expect that viewers watching in the same language are going to get different dialog, changes to the story, or anything of that nature.

Comment: Sending differently formatted versions of a film to different theaters is standard these days, and the only reason you're even hearing about it is for this film is because Disney saw another way to generate publicity and possibly trick movie-goers into seeing the film multiple times.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

She was shouting:

> Rocket, Teefs, Floor go now!

[image: screenshot of scene]

Video of the scene (relevant part starts at 00:29):

Answer (score 2):

She's shouting for them to run away:

> "Floor Rocket Teefs go!"

(I may have the exact order of names wrong, as I've only seen the movie one time.)